# Double Quoted data error in BigQuery CSV upload

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

While uploading data from Google Sheets to BigQuery, the "comments" field contains data like as follows

[image]

```
function pushToBQ(projectId, datasetId, tableId) {
  var fileId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

  var jobSpec = { configuration: {
      load: {
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        },
        allowJaggedRows: true,
        writeDisposition: 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        allowQuotedNewlines: true,
        schema: {
          fields: [ 
            {name: 'User_id', type: 'STRING'},
            {name: 'email', type: 'STRING'},
            {name: 'Comments', type: 'STRING'},
          ] 
        }
      }
    }
  };

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId);
  var MAX_ROWS = 50000;
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("xyz");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var csvdata = "";
  for (var row = 1; row < data.length && row < MAX_ROWS + 1; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
      var cell = data[row][col].toString();
      if (cell.indexOf(",") != -1) {
        csvdata += "\"" + cell + "\"";
      } else {
        csvdata += cell;
      }

      if (col < data[row].length - 1) {
         csvdata += ",";
      }
    }
    csvdata += "\r\n";

  }

  var data = Utilities.newBlob(csvdata, "application/octet-stream");
  BigQuery.Jobs.insert(jobSpec, projectId, data);
}

function daily_upload(){
  pushToBQ("dev", "sampledataset",'sampletable');
}
```

Please provide me the solution , I want to upload the comments as it is, with out replacing them with spaces.

Comment: You get this issue because you have not escaped the quotes in the original comment fields. You *must* do that.

Comment: Please review related BigQuery questions and indicate 1) the exact error you get, and 2) what your attempts to resolve this issue entailed and the results from attempting them.

Answer (score 1):

Options other than creating CSV from your sheet and then importing that CSV into BigQuery:

1. [Read from your sheet in BigQuery by creating an 'external table'](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive) (requires that data is in the first tab of the sheet).  You can then copy from that external table to a true bigquery table.
2. use `BigQuery.Tabledata.insertAll()` to insert data to a table as JSON, rather than having to format CSV.